# Boltzmann Distribution With Constraints

Tags: inequality, probability-distributions, statistical-mechanics

I have a problem with showing the existence of Boltzmann distribution given some constraints.

Consider $p_1,...,p_n$ a Boltzmann distibution, where $p_i=\frac{\epsilon^{-\beta \cdot E_i}}{\sum_{j}^{} \epsilon^{-\beta \cdot E_j}}$.

Define the expected value $E = \sum_{i}^{} p_i \cdot E_i$.

Whether Boltzmann distribution exists in the three following cases?

1. $E_1<E<\frac{\sum_{i}{} E_i}{n}$
2. $E>\frac{\sum_{i}{} E_i}{n}$
3. $E=\frac{\sum_{i}{} E_i}{n}$

Let's consider the first case, when $E_1<E<\frac{\sum_{i}{} E_i}{n}$.

$E= \sum_{i}^{} p_i \cdot E_i  = \sum_{i}^{} \frac{e^{-\beta \cdot E_i}}{\sum_{j}^{} \epsilon^{- \beta \cdot E_j}}$.

Whether $E_1<\sum_{i}^{} \frac{e^{-\beta \cdot E_i}}{\sum_{j}^{} \epsilon^{- \beta \cdot E_j}}<\frac{\sum_{i}^{} E_i}{n}$?

The problem is so far I don't have an idea how to approach the solution.

Would appreciate any help.

**Addendum:** I would like to thank joriki for his great answer.

Let's try to make rigorous proof.

When $E_1<E_2$, by definition of Boltzmann probability $p_1>p_2$. Show that $E<\frac{E_1+E_2}{2}$. When $p_1>p_2$ and $p_1+p_2=1$ then $p_1>0.5$ and $p_2<0.5$.

$E_1p_1 + E_2p_2 $? $0.5E_1 + 0.5E_2$

$E_1p_1 + E_2(1-p_1) $? $0.5E_1 + 0.5E_2$

$E_1(p_1-0.5) + E_2(0.5-p_1) $? $0$

Where $p_1-0.5>0$ and $0.5-p_1<0$, because $p_1>0.5$.

I am really stuck here.

At least let's show that $E_1<E$

$E_1p_1 + E_2p_2$?$E_1$

$E_1(p_1-1) + E_2p_2$ ? 0

$-E_1p_2 + E_2p_2$ ?0

$p_2(E_2-E_1)>0$

Let's try to it show for the general case $\sum_{i}^{} E_ip_i > E_1$

*[sorry for the last attempt]*

$\sum_{i}^{} E_ip_i $?$ E_1$

$E_1p_1 + \sum_{i=2}^{} E_ip_i$?$ E_1$

$E_1(p_1-1) + \sum_{i=2}^{} E_ip_i$?$0$

*$p_1+...+p_n =1$*

$E_1(-\sum_{i=2}^{} p_i) + \sum_{i=2}^{} E_ip_i$?$0$

$\sum_{i=2}^{} p_i (\sum_{i=2}^{} E_i - E_1) > 0$

In addition, finally I get the idea in 2) the trick with derivative, unfortunately I cannot get it equal to negative variance, but I am keep trying, the computations get very long. But one minor point, by showing that derivative is negative we conclude that $E$ is a concave function with maximum at $\beta = 0$, which is exactly like in the 3) case where the distribution exists, so why Boltzmann distribution is impossible in 2)?

Comment: The wording is slightly unclear. I suspect that what you mean is whether there exist Boltzmann distributions such that the condition (1., 2. or 3.) is satisfied?

Comment: @joriki, exactly ,thank you for the comment, I think in general it simply possible to show with inequalities but I don't have an idea how to proceed from what I wrote down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Take $E_1\lt E_2$; then $p_1\gt p_2$ and thus $E_1\lt E\lt(E_1+E_2)/2$.
2. This is impossible for non-negative $\beta$. To see this, form $\partial E/\partial\beta$, show that it's the negative variance of $E$ and thus non-positive, and infer that $E$ is never greater than its value at $\beta=0$, which is the mean.
3. This occurs either if all $E_i$ are equal, or for $\beta=0$, corresponding to $T\to\infty$.

[*Edit in response to addendum:*]

For 1., you started out on the right path; then you can write

\begin{align}
p_1E_1+p_2E_2
&=
p_1\left(\frac{E_1+E_2}2+\frac{E_1-E_2}2\right)+p_2\left(\frac{E_1+E_2}2-\frac{E_1-E_2}2\right)
\\
&=
(p_1+p_2)\frac{E_1+E_2}2+(p_1-p_2)\frac{E_1-E_2}2
\\
&=
\frac{E_1+E_2}2+(p_1-p_2)\frac{E_1-E_2}2
\\
&\lt
\frac{E_1+E_2}2\;.
\end{align}

I'm not sure what you're trying to do to show that the mean is $\gt E_1$. The mean of elements that are not all equal is greater than the least of the elements; I doubt that you're expected to prove that ab initio.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, unfortunately I am slightly confused by 1 and 2, could you please elaborate a little more.

Comment: @rrapido: It makes a lot more sense for you to tell me which part you don't understand and what you don't understand about it than for me to guess and likely explain the wrong things.

Comment: I've added addendum with my current progress, actually the lack of progress, I am very sorry for naivety, with hope for your help.

Comment: @rrapido: Thanks for the very detailed response; I'll update the answer shortly.

Comment: @rrapido: I responded to your attempts at solving 1. About 2., you didn't show what problem you encountered in trying to compute the derivative. I'm not sure what you mean by "But don't understand why derivative should be equal to variance?" -- it's not that it *should* be equal; it just happens to turn out that way when you compute it.

Comment: I fixed the part with $E > E_1$ , it looks like the proof for the general case make sense. Thank you very much for the part $E < \frac{E_1+E_2}{2}$. I still have some hard time to show this for the general case. I've added at the end the question regarding 2) case, please take a look. Thank you very much!